# How do I clear older Firefox caches retaining new

Tags: firefox

Firefox does keep cache. The default is 300MB. I want to clear the oldest caches of say N days. But I couldn't find any way to do so.

How do I do this? Is there any way? (I saw chrome has a day based cache clearance settings but they only allow newer caches.)

Comment: Is this not off-topic here?

Comment: Why do you think it is?

Comment: Because this is likely to be done inside `about:config`, which is independent of any OS. Why not ask this in firefox forum?

Comment: Faq says running third party applications on Ubuntu is on-topic here. If you think it is an off-topic question you can flag. http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Well, that is a bit imprecise. I don't think it means that any question on anything I do is on-topic, as long as I am using Ubuntu. But fine. Just saying.

Comment: @Anwar The closest thing I have found so far is [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/precise-clear-history/), which unfortunately doesn't work for Firefox 45 onwards because of a bug.